# Profiling a Scala Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to profile my sSpark scala applications to figure out the parts of the code which i have to optimize. I enabled `-Xprof` in `--driver-java-options` but this is not of much help to me as it gives lot of granular details. I am just interested to know how much time each function call in my application is taking time.
As is other Stack Overflow questions, many people suggested YourKit but it is not inexpensive. So i would like to use something which is not costly in fact free of cost.

Are there any better ways to solve this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend you to use directly the UI that spark provides. It provides a lot of information and metrics regarding time, steps, network usage, etc...

You can check more about it here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Also, in the new Spark version (1.4.0) there is a nice visualizer to understand the steps and stages of your spark jobs.

Answer (score 8):

As you said, profiling a distributed process is trickier than profiling a single JVM process, but there are ways to achieve this.

You can use sampling as a thread profiling method. Add a java agent to the executors that will capture stack traces, then aggregate over these stack traces to see which methods your application spends the most time in.

For example, you can use [Etsy's statsd-jvm-profiler](https://github.com/etsy/statsd-jvm-profiler) java agent and configure it to send the stack traces to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/downloads/) and then aggregate them using [Flame Graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html).

For more information, check out my post on profiling Spark applications: https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2016/09/08/spark-in-flames-profiling-spark-applications-using-flame-graphs/

Answer (score 7):

I've written an article and a script recently, that wraps `spark-submit`, and generates a flame graph after executing a Spark application.

Here's the article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/profiling-spark-applications-one-click-michael-spector

Here's the script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spektom/spark-flamegraph/master/spark-submit-flamegraph

Just use it instead of regular `spark-submit`.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael: can this be used with gcloud spark submit jobs ?

Comment: @User9102d82, looks like there's [an issue](https://github.com/spektom/spark-flamegraph/issues/8) when using it with dataproc.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [JVM Profiler](https://github.com/uber-common/jvm-profiler) released by UBER.

JVM Profiler is a tool developed by UBER for analysing JVM applications in distributed environment. It can attach Java agent to executors of Spark/Hadoop application in a distributed way and collect various metrics at runtime. It allows to trace arbitrary java methods/arguments without source code change (similar to Dtrace).

Here is the [blog post](https://eng.uber.com/jvm-profiler/).

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest to check out [sparklens](http://sparklens.qubole.com/). This is profiling and performance prediction tool for Spark with built-in Spark Scheduler simulator. It provides an overall idea about how efficiently your cluster resources are utilized and what effects(approximately) a change in cluster resource configuration could have on the performance.

Comment: I generated a sparklens report for our cluster (http://sparklens.qubole.com/report_view/616b961beb11dc0298b1) and it shows negative values which we are unable to understand. We also tried to reach out to the github page for assistance but nothing so far.